# I want to stop automatic explosion effect of canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, gsap

I'm trying to stop automatic explosion effect of canvas please [`click me`](https://jsfiddle.net/ttcy24ag/2/) to see the example and want this effect only one time when user click on click me button.

Any help appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry i didn't mentioned the link.
here you can see the example https://jsfiddle.net/ttcy24ag/2/

Comment: Put `setTimeout(() => loop = () => {},2000);` in the click event and the animation will stop in 2 seconds. Change the 2000 to the number milliseconds at which to stop.